# little lags animating large objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, velocity.js

I recently discovered velocity.js, which is really great. I am animating a pretty big SVG graphic, which slides through the screen (about 5k px width). It looks somehow like this:

```
$($(element)[index]).velocity({
    translateX: [-distanceMove], 
    translateZ : 0
}, {
    duration: 60000, 
    easing: "linear"
});
```

However, I experience little (really minor) lags in all browsers. Does anyone know how to get rid of these? I am guessing it could be the size of the SVG. Should I cut it into pieces? Would that make a difference?

cheers,

Comment: if it's a long running animation it could be due to JS GC. could you add a fiddle with a demo?

Comment: Mmh, i just saw that the official demo itself has these tiny lags: [velocity demo](http://julian.com/research/velocity/demo.html). Maybe it's just my old computer, haha :)